# RAM Memory Not Recognized

Tags: 16.04, ram, memtest

Today I put a new 8GB RAM, replacing the old 4GB one, but it's not recognized by Ubuntu nor by Windows 10 (I have dual OS).

Now I have only 4GB recognized because I didn't replaced both of them.

I ran a memtest86+ test and everything was just fine, without errors. I saw the new RAM informations at the SPD thing in memtest86+.

Here are the results of:

`dmesg | grep memory` command:

```
[    0.000000] Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [ffff880000096000] 96000 size 24576
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000] Reserving Intel graphics stolen memory at 0xcbe00000-0xcfdfffff
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009c000-0x0009cfff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009d000-0x0009ffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000dffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000e0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb9985000-0xb998bfff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xba214000-0xba497fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc98eb000-0xc9afffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc9e1a000-0xcab28fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcab29000-0xcaffefff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcb000000-0xcbbfffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcbc00000-0xcfdfffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xcfe00000-0xf7ffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfc000000-0xfebfffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec01000-0xfecfffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed03fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed04000-0xfed1bfff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed1c000-0xfed1ffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed20000-0xfedfffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee01000-0xfeffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff000000-0xffffffff]
[    0.032437] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.034019] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 28K (ffffffff820b2000 - ffffffff820b9000)
[    0.951478] Freeing initrd memory: 40740K (ffff88003305e000 - ffff880035827000)
[    0.951727] Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    1.023211] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1476K (ffffffff81f41000 - ffffffff820b2000)
[    1.023543] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1872K (ffff88000182c000 - ffff880001a00000)
[    1.023877] Freeing unused kernel memory: 176K (ffff880001dd4000 - ffff880001e00000)
```

`dmidecode --type memory` command:

```
# dmidecode 3.0
/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point: Permission denied
Scanning /dev/mem for entry point.
/dev/mem: Permission denied
l@l:~$ sudo dmidecode --type memory
[sudo] password for l: 
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Hynix/Hyundai
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number:                   
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000C
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
```

`sudo lshw` command:

```
   description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 3835MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 2687MHz
          capacity: 3100MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0b
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:48 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:51 memory:f7a1c000-f7a1ffff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7a10000-f7a17fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series USB xHCI HC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:44 memory:f7a00000-f7a0ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-21-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-21-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=9 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Mouse
                   product: USB Gaming Mouse
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.11
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Video
                   product: USB Camera
                   vendor: 04081-00052400E9E8W6
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@1:6
                   version: 0.02
                   serial: 200901010001
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 8 Series HECI #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:49 memory:f7a24000-f7a2401f
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: 8 Series HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:50 memory:f7a18000-f7a1bfff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f7900000-f79fffff
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:45 memory:f7915000-f7915fff memory:f7900000-f790ffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
                logical name: enp2s0f1
                version: 12
                serial: ac:9e:17:9c:2b:22
                size: 1Gbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
                resources: irq:47 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7914000-f7914fff memory:f7910000-f7913fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 memory:f7800000-f78fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlp3s0
                version: 01
                serial: 40:e2:30:58:5c:e7
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:19 memory:f7800000-f787ffff memory:f7880000-f788ffff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:43 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: 3D controller
                product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: a2
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:52 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 8 Series LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:46 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7a22000-f7a227ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 8 Series SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7a21000-f7a210ff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: 8 Series Thermal
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7a20000-f7a20fff
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: Samsung SSD 850
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 1B6Q
             serial: S21JNXAG905520Y
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=09136279
           *-volume:0
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 6939f803-affa-46dc-9d1a-aac12c594658
                size: 419GiB
                capacity: 419GiB
                capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2016-04-21 17:58:45 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2016-04-28 18:33:11 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2016-04-28 18:26:42 state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: 3.1
                serial: 620a-5ce0
                size: 498MiB
                capacity: 500MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2016-04-22 09:20:17 filesystem=ntfs label=System Reserved modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 3.1
                serial: 38cb1e54-8a86-774e-984d-0077359ae116
                size: 46GiB
                capacity: 46GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2016-04-22 09:20:20 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 3
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: CDDVDW SU-228FB
             vendor: TSSTcorp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: AS00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: 4
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: SanDisk SSD U100
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: 6.02
             serial: 132328400701
             size: 22GiB (24GB)
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=9ae5d9db
```

`free -m` command:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3835        1806         948          25        1080        1924
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question but... are you using a 32 bits SO?

Comment: No. Both OS are 64bit.

Comment: Please add the make and model of your hardware.

Comment: `lshw` command isn't for hardware info? That's what I put out there.

Comment: @23840034 Did you find a solution to your problem? I have the exact same issue with the OS seeing only 8Gb out of 16Gb.